# Wifi not getting connected

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have been trying to connect to a wifi network programatically. If I connect it from settings and then try to connect programatically, it works. Otherwise it is not working. It is getting connected and whithin 1 second it is getting disconnected.

```
 public void saveWpaConfig(String SSID, String Password)
{
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.hiddenSSID = true;
    conf.priority = 1000;
    conf.SSID = "\"" + SSID + "\"";
    conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + Password + "\"";
    conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
    conf.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);

    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
    conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);

    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);

    conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
    conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);

    conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
    conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
    int res = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
    boolean es = wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
    Log.d("", "saveConfiguration returned " + es);
    wifiManager.disconnect();
    boolean bRet = wifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);
    Log.i("", "enableNetwork bRet = " + bRet);
    wifiManager.reconnect();
}
```

Comment: I had worked on Wifi Manager a way time before but what I do remember till date is that first step is to scan all available wifi device, they you check out that is the required SSID or Wifi Mac address is one out of them, if YES, then you proceed with that ScanResult object to make connection AND you need to know that "scanResult.capabilities.toUpperCase()" fetches out the type of Security is has like WEP, WPA etc. And every security algorithm has a different style and methods to make a stable connection.

Comment: I have used same code for Open networks. Works fine. Does it get disconnected for open Network as well ? See here is the code https://github.com/rohitksingh/Bulucu/blob/fe43b24e099650937ee0940f4419fb9bffba8965/Bulucu/app/src/main/java/com/freewifi/rohksin/freewifi/Utilities/WifiUtility.java#L36